# In Android P how do we record audio for a VOIP app when we're in the background?

Tags: android, audio, android-9.0-pie

Android P.  After sitting on the desk not moving for a few minutes, the Android security feature that prevents background recording kicks in and we're no longer able to record.  If you bring the app to the foregound, we start getting a good audio stream again.  I assume we're hitting [this Android issue/change](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/system/sepolicy/+/577303).

We're whitelisted for doze mode (confirmed by looking at 'adb shell dumpsys deviceidle'), we have a foreground service with a displayed notification, we've taken a wakelock.  Still get no audio recording after two minutes of sitting on the desk with the screen off.  (That's a normal use case for us; if you're on a voip call, it's very common to put your call on speaker and not touch your phone for an hour or more while you talk.  It's also common for users to switch away from our app and expect to keep talking.)

What else do we need to do for Android P to be able to record audio when we're not the foreground app and the phone's sitting idle (and physically not moving) for long periods?

Comment: Are you implementing your VOIP as a custom [`ConnectionService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService)? I have only vague idea about it, but perhaps being bound to by systems Telecom will prevent it from going idle.